# Change the layout or cols value of md-grid-list based on screen size

Tags: angular, grid, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I am using Grid List of [angular material 2](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples).

Here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/0v9R3e4x3tThh85147x7?p=preview

Here I have defined a grid list of three columns and there are three tiles (showing in a row as defined as three columns).

I want to change the layout direction of tiles like if the screen size gets shrunk at a certain point then all the tiles should be in column one below the other that is somehow value of `cols` parameter changed to 1. How is it possible? Is it possible with flex-layout ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Only for a div:**

To apply column change only to a div, add an `elementRef` to the div for example, `#gridView`. Use this ref to get the `width` of the div containing the grid-list. Then we can use `[fxShow]` from `flex-layout` when `div` width changes and set the col number based on the size of the `div`.

html:

```html
<div style="background: skyblue" #gridView [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': divSize }"
    [fxShow]="setColNum(gridView.style.width)">
    <md-grid-list [cols]="columnNum" rowHeight="100px">
        <md-grid-tile>
            A
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            B
        </md-grid-tile>

        <md-grid-tile>
            C
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

ts:

```js
@ViewChild('gridView') gridView;
      
columnNum = 3;

divSize = 900;

setColNum(div){
  // console.log(div);
  if(this.gridView.nativeElement.offsetWidth < 400){
    this.columnNum = 1;
  }
  if(this.gridView.nativeElement.offsetWidth >= 400 
      && this.gridView.nativeElement.offsetWidth < 800){
    this.columnNum = 2;
  }
  if(this.gridView.nativeElement.offsetWidth >= 800){
    this.columnNum = 3;
  }
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/p6c4yIg5Dt2weSHUHTEe?p=preview)

**Full Viewport:**

Yes, it's possible with `flex-layout`. In my testing I found that the `fxLayout` api doesn't play well with `md-grid-list`, so as an alternative, I used it's `MediaChange, ObservableMedia` features to detect screen size and set column number based on that.

[Edited Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ocrQR6KofMglPwSgNOk?p=preview), col size changes to 2 and 1 for screen size `sm` and `xs`.

html:

```
<md-grid-list [cols]="columnNum" 
              rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile>
    A
  </md-grid-tile>
  
  <md-grid-tile>
    B
  </md-grid-tile>
  
  <md-grid-tile>
    C
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

component.ts:

```
columnNum = 0;

constructor(media: ObservableMedia) {
  media.asObservable()
    .subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      // alert(change.mqAlias);  
      console.log(change.mqAlias);
      if(change.mqAlias == 'xs'){
        this.columnNum = 1;
      }
      else if(change.mqAlias == 'sm'){
        this.columnNum = 2;
      }
      else{
        this.columnNum = 3;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: as this will work on total view port, is it possible based on the div size id grid list is in div container?

Comment: Thanks!! In case of div you are setting width manually but if the div size changes based on some other compnent on screen dynamically

Comment: is there any way to shrink the size of font for the same?

Comment: You can do it by manipulating the `font-size`. I have updated the plunker demo. Let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 4):

The number of columns depending on (changing) width of a mat-grid-list can be set like this :

in html :

```
<div #theContainer>
     <mat-grid-list cols="{{columnNum}}">
            <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let aTile of allTiles">
               ...
            </mat-grid-tile>
     </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

in TS :

```
 @ViewChild('theContainer') theContainer;
 columnNum = 3; //initial count
 tileSize = 230; //one tile should have this width

 setColNum(){
    let width = this.theContainer.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.columnNum = Math.trunc(width/this.tileSize);
  }

  //calculating upon loading 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setColNum();
  }

  //recalculating upon browser window resize
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.setColNum();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a clean answer that ultimately solved it for me!

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to change the number of columns using [Covalent's media queries](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/media).

It could look something like this:

```
<md-grid-list cols="_mediaService.query('gt-sm') ? 3 : 2" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile>
    A
  </md-grid-tile>

  <md-grid-tile>
    B
  </md-grid-tile>

  <md-grid-tile>
    C
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Also, you seem to not understand how `<md-grid-list works>` It takes care of the layout. You do not need to use fxLayout with it.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically update the column size of `md-grid-list` I put variables in for `md-cols-gt-sm` and `md-cols-sm` and then update them in my controller. For example they look like

```
md-cols-gt-sm="{{nav.variable}}" md-cols-sm="{{nav.variable}}"
```

Cheers