# Angular 2 md-grid-list set column with screen size

Tags: angular, angular-material

I searched for this topic but I did not find a subject that was fitting my problem.
I'm trying to set column size to the elements inside my md-grid-list by doing so:

```
 <md-grid-list md-cols-gt-md="3" md-cols-md="2" rowHeight="180px">
        <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let pic of pictures" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
          <md-card class="grey-card">
            <img class="picture" md-list-avatar src="../../../assets/android.png">

          </md-card>
        </md-grid-tile>
      </md-grid-list>
```

But the md-cols do not work is it because columns shouldn't be set this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link to help me solve the problem:
[Change the layout or cols value of md-grid-list based on screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188134/change-the-layout-or-cols-value-of-md-grid-list-based-on-screen-size)

Also to make it work I had to install the flex layout module and used this: 
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/457
and this:
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/NPM-Installs